# What am I doing wrong with this div?

Tags: css, html

Evidently something isn't right here. The CSS for #wrap just isn't showing up. Not sure what I'm doing wrong. Please look over my code below:

```
<html>
<head>
<title> WhateverWorks </title>
<style>
body{
background-color: #0066CC;
color: white;
}
h1{
font-size: 18pt;
color: white;
font-style: bold;
font-family: calibri;
}
#wrap{
border solid 2px #000;
background-color: #00033;
width: 800px;
height: 200px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrap">
This site is under construction...<br /> please see our facebook page for now!
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`font-style: bold;`

-> It's `font-weight: bold;`

`border solid 2px #000;`

-> There's a colon (:) missing: `border:solid 2px #000;`

`background-color: #00033;`

-> There's a number missing, hex has 6 numbers

/edit: Try http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/ if your CSS isn't working.

Answer (score 5):

You forgot a `:` after border

```
border: solid 2px #000;
```